# How to combine two flowable and get only same emission values?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

```
        val flowable01 = Flowable.fromArray(listOf(
            Value(epoch = 1,string ="apple"),
            Value(epoch = 2,string ="apple"), 
            Value(epoch = 3,string ="apple"),
            Value(epoch = 4,string ="apple"), 
            Value(epoch = 5,string ="apple"),
            Value(epoch = 6,string ="apple"), 
            Value(epoch = 7,string ="apple"),
            Value(epoch = 8,string ="apple"), 
            Value(epoch = 9,string ="apple"),
            Value(epoch = 10,string ="apple"), 
            ))
        val flowable02 = Flowable.fromArray(listOf(
            Value(epoch = 2,string ="orange"), 
            Value(epoch = 3,string ="orange"),
            Value(epoch = 5,string ="orange"),
            Value(epoch = 8,string ="orange"), 
            Value(epoch = 10,string ="orange"), 
            ))
            
        flowable01.filter { it.epoch == flowable02.emission.epoch }
                  .map { Value(it.epoch, "juice") }
```

How to combine two flowable and filter out only same values from emissions and map it to another data class?
Maybe using combineLatest/zip

```
//Result:  
Value(epoch = 2,string ="juice")
Value(epoch = 3,string ="juice")
Value(epoch = 5,string ="juice")
Value(epoch = 8,string ="juice")
Value(epoch = 10,string ="juice")
```

Comment: Are the numbers in increasing order? Is one sequence always a subset of the other sequence? Can numbers repeat?

Comment: numbers in epoch (time), in increasing order and not repeated. Yes second flowable is the subset of first. @Progman

Comment: In this example yes, but its in data class, and I need the values from both of them, to make another data class)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual situation you have and what you are trying to do. What you describe in the comment is a different problem than the one you described in the question.

Comment: edited, this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap`:

```java
flowable01.flatMap { first ->
  flowable02.filter { second -> first.epoch == second.epoch }
  .map { second -> Value(second.epoch, "Juice") }
}
```

If flowable02 is an external datasource, you may not want to re-query it each time so you can make it cached upfront:

```java
flowable02cache = flowable02.cache()

flowable01.flatMap { first ->
  flowable02cache.filter { second -> first.epoch == second.epoch }
  .map { second -> Value(second.epoch, "Juice") }
}
```

If you want to exploit the ordering in each source, that's more complicated on the merging step:

```java
Single.zip(flowable01.toList(), flowable02.toList()) { first, second ->

    val result = ArrayList<Value>()

    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i < first.length && j < second.length) {
        if (first[i].epoch == second[j].epoch) {
            result.add(Value(first[i].epoch, "Juice"))
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (first[i].epoch < second[j].epoch) {
            i++;
        }
        if (first[i].epoch > second[j].epoch) {
            j++;
        }
    }

    result;
}
```